# Para que serve o proxy creation no entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Qual o propósito de desabilitar essa funcionalidade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proxies são necessários para dois recursos:

- **lazy load** - as propriedades de navegação são carregadas uma vez que você acessou a primeira vez
- **Rastreamento de alterações dinâmicas** - se você modificar qualquer propriedade na entidade, o contexto é notificado sobre essa alteração e definir o estado da entidade. Se o rastreamento de alterações dinâmicas não for utilizado, o contexto deve usar o rastreamento de alterações de instantâneo, o que significa que todas as mudanças antes de salvar ocorrem, explorando todas as propriedades, mesmo que não tenham sido alteradas.

Ambas as técnicas têm outros requisitos:

- **lazy load** - todas as propriedades de navegação na entidade devem ser virtual. O carregamento preguiçoso deve estar ativado.
- **Rastreamento dinâmico de alterações** - todas as propriedades mapeadas devem ser virtual.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198563/entity-framework-proxy-creation

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, tinha lido o link que passou porém não estava bem claro

Answer (score 1):

A principio não vejo proposito (beneficio) nenhum, a não ser quer você queira trabalha em um ambiente que não seja preciso um rastreamento ou que queira fazer isso manualmente.

Um ponto que poderia ser útil seria um caso que você precise apenas leitura dos dados, nesse senário fazer o rastreamento não teria sentido ele serviria mais na hora de persistir as informações, então você poderia esta usando o EF para ler as informações e usar o Dapper para persistir por exemplo, ou uma leitura em uma base de dados Read Only. Nesses senário você teria uma melhor performa-se.

É necessário entender que o proxy representa uma instância que ainda não foi preenchida com dados do banco de dados, mas só conhece sua própria ID. Sempre que uma propriedade que é mapeada para o banco de dados é acessada, a subclasse de proxy executará a carga do banco de dados, de modo que a carga seja transparente para o código do cliente.